# Why does it give me an error message when I use git add?

Tags: git

I'm trying to add all the files using `git all` but an error message returns:

Error:

`git: 'add' is not a git command.`

I looked at git solutions but couldn't find any solution

Comment: You probably want to use [`git add --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---all)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using --all instead of individual filenames will stage all changes (new, modified, and deleted) files.

You should use:

`git add --all`

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/git/git_staging_environment.asp

Answer (score -1):

To add all files I generally use

```
git add *
```

Can you try that?

Answer (score -1):

`git all` is not a valid git command.

You should use `git add .` to add all files.
Then you can commit them.

I recommend this [Google Course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/introduction-git-github). It is very complete.